# collection repeat, filtrar por variables

Tags: ionic

Trabajo con Ionic 1, tengo un **collection repeat** que quiero filtrar del a siguiente manera:

En el controlador tengo dos variables: `$scope.diaHoy` y `$scope.mesHoy`.

En el `collection-repeat`, traigo `item.mes` e `item.dia`.

`ion-item collection-repeat="item in usuarios ...........`

Quiero mostrar aquellos registros en que 
`$scope.diaHoy == dia and $scope.mesHoy == mes`

pero no trae nada el **collection**. Si saco el filtro, funciona perfecto.

Éste es mi código:

```
<ion-item class="fondodiv item-icon-center item-text-wrap" collection-repeat="item in usuarios | {{item.dia == diaHoy}}" overflow-scroll="false" >
```

no hay más que esto, excepto un div interno.

```
<div class="item item-avatar"><img src="img/{{item.leg}}.png"> </div>
```

Comment: Guille, podrías agregar el código completo donde haces esto?

Comment: <ion-item class="fondodiv item-icon-center item-text-wrap" collection-repeat="item in usuarios | {{item.dia == diaHoy}}" overflow-scroll="false" > no hay más que esto, excepto un div interno. <div class="item item-avatar"><img src="img/{{item.leg}}.png"> </div> gracias!

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código, no la pongas como un comentario

Answer (score -1):

Resuelto, gracias

```
filter: { dia : diaHoy, mes : mesHoy }
```